# How to make "Google Play Service"-like overlay prompt on android?

Tags: android, android-activity, popup, window, native

Sorry for my bad English.

I need to make an native SDK to show an overlay popup window to show a message on the top of the current activity.

The window will show about several seconds and then dismiss.

When the window is showing, the content behind needs to be active.

I try several methods, such as `startActivity` with not touchable and `popupWindow.showAtLocation`, but no one can act as the same behavior like Google Play Service-overlay window when you log in using Google account in applications.

I cannot get the current activity context or the current view since I don't have the `GET_TASK` permission.

Google Play popup overlay window Screenshot: 
[image: http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2013/05/googleplaygameservices619pxhedimg.jpg]

I need advise, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think you need to create a showCase for your app.

[This library](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) will help you .

if you want `more customization`. you have to create a Service. [And read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top) if you want an overlay.